# Googlebot adding /feed at the end of my URLs

Tags: feed, google-search

I have seen on Google Webmaster that the crawler is searching for URLs by adding `/feed`at their end.

e.g.

```
4    holiday-fashion-from-daisy-darche/feed/       404         8/4/14
```

This obviously leads to a 404 error.

Why is google doing this?
How can I prevent this?

I found this related article:
http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/web/GooglebotCrawlingFeeds

Answer (score 1):

Adding feed to the end of URLs is not an error, nor should it result in 404's.

WordPress supports sending most any page's data as a feed, and Google crawls them for URLs and other information along these lines.

Comment: ok I have now seen that these URLs do not exist. They represent posts that have been deleted. Why are they still being accessed by Google?

Comment: Maybe there were links to them from somewhere else? Or just that Google remembers URLs and crawls them again in the future to check for changes.